# How to check in $\{x,\cos(x),1\}$ is linearly independent or dependent.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been working on this question about how to check whether $\{x,\cos(x),1\}$ is linearly independent or not.

My attempt:

We need to show $c_{1}x + c_{2}\cos(x) + c_{3} = 0$

When $x=0$
$$ c_{2} + c_{3} = 0 $$

When $x=\pi$
$$ c_{1}\pi - c_{2} + c_{3} = 0 $$
$$ c_{1} = \frac{2c_{2}}{\pi} $$

After this I do not know where to go or what we can say about linear independence based on these relationships. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: And when $x=2\pi$?

Comment: Cf. the [Wronskian](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian)

Comment: If we choose the order of the functions appropriately, the matrix whose determinant is the Wronskian is triangular, making it especially easy to compute the Wronskian.

Comment: Take your linear relation $c_{1}x + c_{2}\cos(x) + c_{3} = 0$.  Apply derivative operator twice to confirm $c_2=0$, once to confirm $c_1=0$ and no times to confirm $c_3=0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We also have for $x=\frac \pi 2$

$$c_{1}\frac \pi 2 + c_{2}0 + c_{3} = 0 \implies c_3=-\frac \pi 2 c_1$$

which with $c_{2} + c_{3} = 0$ and $c_{1} = \frac{2c_{2}}{\pi}$ implies $c_1=1$, $c_2=\frac \pi 2$, $c_3=-\frac \pi 2$, but for $x=2\pi$

$$2\pi + \frac \pi 2 -\frac \pi 2 = 2\pi \neq 0$$

The latter would require $c_1=0$ which with the previous conditions would imply also $c_2=c_3=0$.

Therefore since we can't find $c_1$, $c_2$ and $c_3$ all simultanously not equal to zero such that $c_1x+c_2\cos(x)+c_3=0$ for all $x$, the given functions are linearly independent.

Comment: So does this mean that this is independent?

Comment: @IllesMoshe Yes because we can't find $c_1$, $c_2$ and $c_3$ not all simultanously equal to zero such that $c_{1}x + c_{2}\cos(x) + c_{3} = 0$ for all $x$.

Comment: Technically, you've just shown $c_1 \neq 1$.  We'd need another argument to conclude. 
 Yes, it's a rather simple argument, but I'm not sure someone asking this question would be able to see it so simply.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Are you referring that for the latter we need $c_1=0$ which with the previous conditions implies $c_2=c_3=0$?

Comment: Yes.  Specifically, some students at this level have trouble making sense of "Assume $c_1 \neq 0$, so WLOG $c_1=1$," even though it's a common simplification.  I presume that's your [unstated] argument?

Comment: @BrianMoehring Thanks a lot! I add this part too

Answer (score 0):

I will continue from where you have stopped.

Now at x= $\frac{\pi}{3}$, you have $c_1$$\frac{\pi}{3}$=$\frac{c_2}{2}$. Which when solved for $c_1$ and $c_2$ using your last equation gives $c_1$=$c_2$=0, but as you pointed out $c_2$+$c_3$=0. This gives $c_1$=$c_2$=$c_3$=0.